# Currency Field Decimal Insert Problem

Tags: apex

I am working with custom soap webservice, I am getting the unit-price amount from external service $399.99 but in sfdc database it is storing as $399 only, the unit-price field is currency(10,3) in salesforce. What is wrong in the below webservice ?

```
global class MainClass
{
  global class Quote-line
  {
    webservice string uprice;
  }

   /----------Method begin---------
  //I am mapping external unitprice to sfdc firld like below

      qlw = new  Quote_Item__c();  
       qlw.Unit_Price__c= integer.valueof(uprice);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [Integer.valueOf(string)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex%5fmethods%5fsystem%5finteger.htm#apex%5fSystem%5fInteger%5fvalueOf), which will give you an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) .. a wole number without decimal values.  If you want to maintain your entire number, you should be using the [Decimal.valueOf(string)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex%5fmethods%5fsystem%5fdecimal.htm#apex%5fSystem%5fDecimal%5fvalueOf%5f3) method.